# Button to run javascript and change css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button i want to expand my sidenav by toggling the class through JQuery.

i've tried JavaScript to solve it since im more familiar with JS.

```
function toggleMenu() {
        var sideEle = document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper");
        var mainEle = document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper");
        sideEle.classList.toggle("sideMenuDisplayed");
        mainEle.classList.toggle("bodyMenuDisplayed");
    };
```

and added `onclick="toggleMenu()"` to the button html but this was also unsuccessful.
I have added borders to both the before and after during debugging to check for the class change.

My current code using JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('sideMenuDisplayed');
      });
```

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: #f07878;
  border: 2px solid red;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.sideMenuDisplayed {
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidenav -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sadebar-nav">
      <li><a href="/account">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact me!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="btn" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" id="homeIcon"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="homeContainer">
      <p>my content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

On button press i get no errors in the console or changes to the page.
The button should toggle the class of `#sidebar-wrapper` and change its properties to `width: 250px;` and border color to blue

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. **Read the error messages**.

Comment: i checked in my local.. its working fine.. plz follow the below code i added..

Comment: Thank you it was simply the closing `});`. i should have caught this but i wasn't getting an error before for some reason. Sorry for the long post of the already solved simple problem

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Please modify to the below codes :

**css**

```
#sidebar-wrapper.sideMenuDisplayed {
    width: 250px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
#menu-toggle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

**jQUERY**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
          $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('sideMenuDisplayed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Answers which explain how code helps the OP are downvoted less often than those which merely give an answer in code.

Comment: Is there any pbm? wheather it's working or not?

Answer (score 1):

The class is already toggle in your code.

You can verify it by looking the class of element in dev tool.

The key is the CSS ID selector is Prior to class selector.

It's called [`Specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types).

> The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
>
> - Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., ::before).
> - Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g.,[type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> - ID selectors (e.g.,#example).
> - Universal selector (*), combinators (+, >, ~, ' ', ||) and negation pseudo-class (:not()) have no effect on specificity. (The
>     selectors declared inside :not() do, however.)

In this example, the #sidebar-wrapper is 1000 score, and .sideMenuDisplayed is only 100 score.
You can just write css style with class selector(which is a common way) or increase the specificity to the style you want to toggle.

Here is the same code you write but with just class selectors :

```js
document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
        var sideEle = document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper");
        var mainEle = document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper");
        sideEle.classList.toggle("sideMenuDisplayed");
        mainEle.classList.toggle("bodyMenuDisplayed");
    }
```

```css
.sidebar-wrapper{
 z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: #f07878;
    border: 2px solid red;
    opacity: 0.9;
    top: 100px; /* add this because the content is masking the button here*/
}
.sideMenuDisplayed {
    width: 250px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="homeBody">

<div class="wrapper">
<!-- Sidenav -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sadebar-nav">
            <li><a href="/account">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact me!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" id="homeIcon"></i></button>
        </div>

    <div class="container" id="homeContainer">
           <p>my content</p>
        </div>
</div>
```